# Python: function foo() in the "for num in foo()" loop multiple times called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Is foo() called in every repeat of the loop?

```
for num in foo():
    # Do something
```

and if that would be inefficient, is this code better?

```
l = foo()
for num in l:
    # Do something
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. In both `foo()` is called only once. The former can be expected to be slightly faster than the latter. Also, `list` is a name of a built-in function/type, and you shouldn't use it as a variable name.

---

You can use Python bytecode disassembler [`dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) to find out what bytecode is produced by CPython:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile('for num in foo():pass', '', 'exec'))
  1           0 SETUP_LOOP              17 (to 20)
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (foo)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              9 GET_ITER
        >>   10 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 19)
             13 STORE_NAME               1 (num)
             16 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           10
        >>   19 POP_BLOCK
        >>   20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             23 RETURN_VALUE
```

In the bytecode above, the loop body starts at `10 FOR_ITER` and continues until `19 POP_BLOCK`. Compare with:

```
>>> dis.dis(compile('l = foo()\nfor num in list:pass', '', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (foo)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (l)

  2           9 SETUP_LOOP              14 (to 26)
             12 LOAD_NAME                1 (l)
             15 GET_ITER
        >>   16 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 25)
             19 STORE_NAME               2 (num)
             22 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           16
        >>   25 POP_BLOCK
        >>   26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             29 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here the loop body starts at position 16, and continues until 25. The bytecode for the loop body is identical; the only differences are the extra opcode `STORE_NAME` to store the return value of `foo()` into `list`, and extra `LOAD_NAME` to retrieve the value from `list`.

Comment: In more detail: *If* `foo` was called every iteration in the first example, then the latter *would* be more efficient. As it is, the latter is less efficient by however long it takes to create and access a variable.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!